# Bash array keys conflicting with existing variables

Tags: arrays, bash

My expectation has been that keys in bash arrays are interpreted as literals, but it seems that's not the case. For example, the following works as expected:

```
$ declare -a mymap
$ mymap[foo]="bar"
```

No problem there, we now have an array with a key, literally `"foo"`. But when I set an environment variable with the same name as the key, and I put special characters in it, it produces a parse error:

```
$ declare -a mymap
$ export foo=" > "
$ mymap[foo]="bar"
-bash: >: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ">")
$ mymap["foo"]="bar"
-bash: >: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ">")
$ mymap['foo']="bar"
-bash: >: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ">")
```

Can anyone explain what I'm missing here? I'm using bash version 4.3.33.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-A` to declare an associative array with string keys. `-a` creates an indexed array whose keys are evaluated in an arithmetic context.

```
$ declare -A mymap
$ export foo=' > '
$ mymap[foo]="bar"
$ echo "${mymap[foo]}"
bar
$ declare -p mymap
declare -A mymap='([foo]="bar" )'
```

Answer (score 1):

Array subscripts are evaluated according to the rules for arithmetic expressions.  That means, for one thing that, for variable names, the `$` is implied.

For example:

```
$ b=1; c=2; mymap[b+c]=sum
$ declare -p mymap
declare -a mymap='([3]="sum")'
```

The problem that you ran into is that `>` is not a valid arithmetic expression.  While `>` is invalid, `2>1` is valid.  Observe:

```
$ export foo=" 2>1 "
$ mymap[foo]="bar"
$ declare -p mymap
declare -a mymap='([1]="bar" [3]="sum")'
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash` (emphasis added):

> An  indexed  array is created automatically if any variable is
>   assigned to using the syntax name[subscript]=value.  **The subscript is
>   treated as an arithmetic expression
>          that must evaluate to a number.**  If subscript evaluates to a number less than zero, it is used as an offset from one greater than
>   the array's maximum index (so  a  subcript  of  -1  refers  to  the  last element of the array).  To explicitly declare an indexed array, use declare -a name ....